# No module named 'selenium' (Python3)

Tags: python, macos, selenium, python-import, importerror

I'm trying to import selenium from a python3 application. I've already installed it asi you can see in the first image.

I also configured the vs code with python3 (image 2).

Both if i try to run it from vs code console or with python3 it says the same error.

> Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
> No module named 'selenium'
> File "/Users/admin/Documents/Bot/bot.py", line 1, in 
> from selenium import webdriver

I've tried several answers from StackOverflow but it didn't seem to work with me.

Note: i'm not using a virtual environment.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Please show us your Selenium code

Comment: whoops, i forget the most important. done!

Comment: Which Python interpreter is that copy of `pip3` bound to? Which Python interpreter are you trying to load Selenium in? (We know the answer to the first question: `/usr/local/lib/python3.9` -- but not the answer to the latter).

Comment: If you know which interpreter needs to be able to load Selenum, use `/path/to/that/copy/of/python -m pip ...` instead of `pip3 ...`

Comment: Sounds like another clear example of why to use `virtualenv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since apparently i have a lot of python3 installed on my system i just created a virtual environment.

go to your program folder and type:

> python3 -m venv virtual-env
> this will create a copy of python3 inside your program folder (in /virtual-env/bin/)

then you need to activate it:

> source /virtual-env/bin/activate
> this will activate your virtual environment, so you can use your own copy of python3 located on your folder.

Once activated, your console will look like this:

> (virtual-env) user:program admin$

thanks to everyone and sorry for the lateness